# Setting selenium browser version via docker compose

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, selenium-grid

I'm running selenium grid through docker compose and targeting the different versions through my desired capabilities.

I have a requirement to test multiple browser versions however at the moment I need to target the full version i.e chrome versions "63.0.3239.132" or "64.0.3282.140"

I want to be able to specify just 63 or 64 etc so that my docker setup can update regularly without the need to update the code.

Is there a way to do this through desired capabilities?

below is my docker compose file

```
version: '2'

services:

  seleniumhub:
      image: selenium/hub:3.9.1-actinium
    ports:
      - 4444:4444

  chrome64:
     image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.9.1-actinium
     depends_on:
       - seleniumhub
     environment:
       HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: seleniumhub
       HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
     ports:
       - 5900

  chrome63:
     image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.8.1-erbium
     depends_on:
       - seleniumhub
     environment:
       HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: seleniumhub
       HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
     ports:
       - 5900
```

below is how i set up my desired capabilities.

```
ICapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

//generic Desktop Browser config':
if (DriverConfig.BrowserName != "")
{ ((DesiredCapabilities)caps).SetCapability("browserName", _browserName); }
else
{ }
if (DriverConfig.Version != "")
{ ((DesiredCapabilities)caps).SetCapability("version", _version); }
else
{ }
if (DriverConfig.Platform != "")
{ ((DesiredCapabilities)caps).SetCapability("platform", _platform); }
else
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `-browser  browserName="chrome,version=63"` in cmd line when register selenium node to sellenium hub, Then you can specify `browerVersion: 63` in capabilities in test script.

So your problem dependent do you have chance to specify `-browser` in registry cmd when use docker setup grid?

Comment: I've updated my question, I have been able to achieve that running via the command line to set up each node however I am using the docker compose method and cant find documentation anywhere for setting the version inside a compose file.